# Visual Basic error 1004 con Tablas Dinamicas

Tags: vba

resulta que en excel tengo una tabla con clientes y sus gastos en cada año. Cada vez que hago clic en el año me abre una tabla dinamica con toda la informacion de ese año del cliente. Lo que quiero es hacer un macro que me genere los informes en un nuevo archivo excel para cada cliente, o sea que traiga toda la informacion pero en un archivo nuevo. El codigo en visual basic es algo asi:

```
Sub Generar_informes()

Dim i As Double
Dim Ini As Double
Dim Fin As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("TablaPrincipal").Select
With Sheets("TablaPrincipal")

Ini = Columns(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Fin = .PivotTables(1).PivotFields("NombreDelCliente").VisibleItems.Count

For i = 1 To Fin

        .Cells(i + Ini, 2).ShowDetail = True

        Sheets(1).Name = .Cells(i + Ini, 1).Value

    ActiveSheet.Select

    ActiveSheet.Move

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name

                ActiveWorkbook.Close False

                    Next i

        End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Y aca esta mas o menos como tengo los datos en la tabla principal:

[image]

El error que me tira es:
"Se ha producido el error '1004' en tiempo de ejecucion:
No se puede asignar la propiedad ShowDetail de la clase Range."

No tengo muchos conocimientos de Visual Basic asi que seguramente es algo basico pero lo necesito para un amigo.
Desde ya muchas gracias.